# Como ocorre a truncagem de um número float ou double?

Tags: arredondamento

Tenho o seguinte trecho:

```
double valor = 1.5;

while(valor >= 0) {
    System.out.println(valor);
    valor -= 0.15;
}
```

A saída será de números truncados devido ao armazenamento de 8 bytes para `double`, correto?

```
(...)
0.30000000000000016
0.15000000000000016
1.6653345369377348E-16
```

Como as linguagens tratam essas situações de truncagem internamente? A operação é simplesmente interrompida para aquele número, retornando-o até o ponto onde ocorreu a truncagem? Qual seria a sequência do número `0.30000000000000016` se não estivesse truncado?

Comment: Acho que é duplicata mesmo. Se não for o autor pode tentar esclarecer. Lá tem a resposta para a pergunta.

Comment: @bfavaretto, as respostas ajudaram bastante, mas já tinha lido algumas explicações -- como a representação binária; o fato do número 0.1 tornar-se uma dízima periódica; e a questão do armazenamento. Porém, minha dúvida é a respeito de como as linguagens (se, de fato, cabe a elas) tratam essa representação. Desculpem, mas não pensei em uma forma de deixar a pergunta mais precisa. Ao formulá-la, não pensei no porquê da truncagem, mas em como ela é executada. No PHP, por exemplo, até o resultado 0.15 os números aparecem arredondados, mas no último número -- que seria 0 --, ele retorna 1.665334...

Comment: Desculpe Caesar, mas continuo não entendendo! Pense assim: você tem `1.5` representado em binário com 64 bits, e `0.15` representado da mesma maneira. Coloque um embaixo do outro e faça a subtração, como faria com um número decimal a lápis, e você tem o resultado em binário, com a precisão possível num double de 64 bits.

Comment: Então, teoricamente, quanto mais precisão em um número, mais bits terão de ser reservados? O `1.5` já fica representado em binário em 64 bits 'originalmente'? É que imaginei que haveria uma perda de informação no processo, entende?

Comment: Sim, o 1.5 fica representado em binário (porém o formato é mais complicado do que eu dei a entender no comentário anterior, veja detalhes na resposta do Miguel Angelo à pergunta linkada como duplicata). Por exemplo, `0.1` [não é representável em binário como float ou double](http://www.exploringbinary.com/why-0-point-1-does-not-exist-in-floating-point/), então quando você atribui esse valor a uma variável double, o que você está guardando é uma aproximação. Então tem mesmo perda de informação, mas não é no cálculo, e sim na representação dos números pelo computador.

Comment: Por fim: se você achar que pode detalhar a pergunta e torná-la distinta o suficiente da que foi considerada duplicata, pode fazer isso, e ela estará sujeita a reabertura (precisa de 5 votos para reabrir).